# Nest elements at row+column combinations respectively in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested

Suppose I have the following NumPy array:

```
arr = np.uint8([
    [[A,B,C], [A,B,C]], 
    [[A,B,C], [A,B,C]] 
])
```

How can I nest each index element in the third dimension of the array such that it becomes:

```
[
[[[A,B,C]], [[A,B,C]]], 
[[[A,B,C]], [[A,B,C]]] 
]
```

I need each instance of `[A, B, C]` nested into its own list, like this: `[[A, B, C]]`.

I can imagine a way of doing this with loops, but it's too inefficient for the large arrays I'm working with. How can I achieve this the NumPy way?

Comment: `arr[...,None]` or `arr[...,np.newaxis]`

Comment: Thank you! Complete newbie here! Could you direct me to more information on how this works?

Comment: `arr.shape` is (2,2,3).  Looks like you want to reshape to (2,2,1,3)

Comment: See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape , also https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#shape-manipulation .

Comment: Thank you for the help everybody! This is great! I really appreciate it!